# Which type of Diffie-Hellman does Tor use?

Tags: encryption, tor, diffie-hellman

Does Tor use Ephemeral DH, Static DH or Anonymous DH? I have heard that the latter two are not secure so I am worried if Tor uses them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tor has had *perfect forward secrecy* since [The Second-Generation Onion Router](https://svn-archive.torproject.org/svn/projects/design-paper/tor-design.html) published in May 2004.

> 4.1  Cells
>
> Onion routers communicate with one another, and with users' OPs, via
> TLS connections with ephemeral keys. Using TLS conceals the data on
> the connection with perfect forward secrecy, and prevents an attacker
> from modifying data on the wire or impersonating an OR.

Furthermore, from the chapter *7 Attacks and Defenses; Active attacks*:

> -- An attacker who learns an OR's TLS private key can impersonate that OR for the TLS key's lifetime, but he must also learn the onion
> key to decrypt create cells (and because of perfect forward secrecy,
> he cannot hijack already established circuits without also
> compromising their session keys). Periodic key rotation limits the
> window of opportunity for these attacks. --

Answer (score 0):

Ephemeral DH, fixed DH, and anonymous DH are variations of DH. Anonymous DH is not recommended, because it does not provide the client with a way of authenticating the server's public key.  Fixed DH is not recommended, because it does not provide perfect forward secrecy (PFS).  See https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Diffie_Hellman for more info.

As pointed out by @EsaJokinen above, TOR protocol supports PFS.  And, authentication of a TOR hidden service's public key is made possible by the fact that the public key is encoded in the service's address.  This is why onion services have addresses like nytimesn7cgmftshazwhfgzm37qxb44r64ytbb2dj3x62d2lljsciiyd.onion instead of nytimes.com.  See https://community.torproject.org/onion-services/overview/ for more info.

Comment: Am I correct that exchanging public key of a server is easier in hidden service than on clear-net sites? since the public key of hidden sites are encoded in its address while the public key of clear-net sites are stored in directories.

Comment: Yes.  In previous versions, the address was a hash of the public key.  But, in v3, the hidden service address contains the service's full ed25519 public key.  See https://blog.torproject.org/v3-onion-services-usage/ for more info.